# React JS & Redux : this.props. is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, typeerror

I have read a lot of threads about my issue *but none of them helped me.*

I developed a JWT authentication app using React.JS and Redux with a django rest framework API as backend.

User information is sent to authenticated user through a GET request :

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "email": "",
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": ""
}
```

### user.actions.js (redux action)

```
export const loadUser = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) {
      axios.get('http://localhost:8000/auth/user/', {
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'token ' + token }
      })
        .then(res => {
          dispatch({ type: USER_LOADED, data: JSON.stringify(res.data) })
        }).catch((error) => {
          // catch later
        })
    }
  };
};
```

### auth.reducers.js

```
import {
  SIGNIN_REQUEST,
  SIGNIN_SUCCESS,
  SIGNIN_FAILURE,
  SIGNOUT,
  USER_LOADED
} from '../_constants/user.constants';

const initialState = { }

export function auth(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SIGNIN_REQUEST:
      return { ...state, isLogging: true }
    case SIGNIN_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, isLogged: true }
    case SIGNIN_FAILURE:
      return { ...state, error: action.data, isLogged: false, isLogging: false }
    case USER_LOADED:
      return { ...state, isLogged: true, user: action.data }
    case SIGNOUT:
      return { }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

### App.js

```
class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) {
      this.props.loadUser();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-scroller">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Router history={History}>
            <Switch>
              ...
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    auth: state.auth
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    loadUser: () => {
      return dispatch(userActions.loadUser());
    }
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Everything works fine. The data is correctly fetch. When I write {this.props.auth.user} in my render method, it displays the data correctly (as sent by the API) :

{"id":1,"email":"","first_name":null,"last_name":null}

But when I try to display a value of the data (id, email, ...) it shows an error : (with map or this.props.auth.user['id']

**TypeError: this.props.auth.user is undefined**

How can I display the data properly ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You are calling `this.props.loadUser();` on `componentDidMount` which means at the first time of `render` being called, the object is undefined. If you stick in a quick `if (this.props.auth !== undefined)` around where you are trying to use the object, then see if that works. If that does, then maybe refactor the code a bit to either return early, or placeholder text.

Comment: when the component first mounts their won't be a value (this.props.auth) ? It is only when the async action is resolved will the props actually have any value? Normally I would apply a turnery to check if there is something before I try and get information (this.props.auth.user....)

Comment: Thanks for both answers! I should keep the life cycle of react components in mind. I simply added an initial state "loading" when the data is being fetched. And with a simple if-else condition the problem is solved :)